# Compute imaginary part of the limit

Tags: limits, complex-numbers, probability-limit-theorems

I am trying to compute the imaginary part of this particular question 
$$\lim_{z\rightarrow i} \frac{iz^3}{z+9 i}$$

Comment: the answer that i get is -i/10. is this right? do i have to do l'hopital rule?

Comment: That is correct. In this case, you want to compute a limit at a point $z = i$ of a function which already is continuous at $z = i$, so all you got to do is to plug in $z = i$ in the expression. You do not have to use l'Hôpitals rule.

Comment: Indeed, you *can't* use l'Hopital's Rule --- it has hypotheses, and its hypotheses do not apply here.

Comment: Neither the numerator nor the denominator goes to $0$, so L'Hôpital is not-applicable. In fact, the function is continuous at $z=i$, so you can simply plug in $z=i$ to get $\frac1{10i}=-\frac1{10}i$. The [imaginary part](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Definition) is $-\frac1{10}$

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{z\rightarrow i} \frac{iz^3}{z+9 i}=$$
$$\lim_{z\rightarrow i} \left(iz^2+9z-\frac{729}{z+9i}-81i\right)$$

Possible intermediate steps:

1) Find the following limit:

$$\lim_{z\rightarrow 0+1i} \frac{iz^3}{z+9 i}$$

2) Applying the quotient rule, write $x_1$ as $x_2$:

$$x_1=\lim_{z\rightarrow i} \frac{iz^3}{z+9 i}$$
$$x_2=\frac{\lim_{z\rightarrow i} iz^3}{\lim_{z\rightarrow i} (z+9i)}$$

So we get:

$$\frac{\lim_{z\rightarrow 0+1i} (0+1i)z^3}{\lim_{z\rightarrow 0+1i} (9(0+1i)+z)}$$

3) $z+9i$ is a plynomial and thus everywhere continuous so $\lim_{z\rightarrow i} (z+9i)=9i+i=10i$:

$$\frac{\lim_{z\rightarrow 0+1i} (0+1i)z^3}{10i}$$

4) $iz^3$ is a polynomial and thus everywhere continuous so $\lim_{z\rightarrow i} iz^3=ii^3=1$:

$$\frac{1}{10i}$$

5) Solution $\frac{1}{10i}=-\frac{i}{10}$:

$$\lim_{z\rightarrow i} \frac{iz^3}{z+9 i}=-\frac{i}{10}$$

Comment: and the imaginary part is $-\frac1{10}$

Comment: The imaginary part is $-\frac{i}{10}$

Comment: The way that I learned it, and the way it is [defined in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Definition), is that "the real number $b$ is called the imaginary part of $a+bi$". This also works better when writing complex numbers as $(a,b)$.

Comment: yes in that form it will be: $0-\frac{1}{10}i$

Comment: and the imaginary part is $-\frac1{10}$

Comment: Yes zero the real